# How to style routerLink DOM element based on guard response

Tags: angular

I am wondering if there is a native angular directive that works like [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) but checks wether the route can activate based on its assigned guard.

To clarify say I have the following route defined:

`{
  path: '1', component: RouteOneComponent,
  canActivate: [RouteOneGuard]
}`

And some HTML that looks like this:

`<p [routerLink]="['1']" routerLinkActive="active">The Link</p>`

Is there a directive that I can use to apply an 'enabled' css class when RouteOneGuard returns true? Something like:

`<p [routerLink]="['1']" routerLinkActive="active" canActivate="enabled">The Link</p>`

Or do I have to create a custom directive for this?

Answer (score 2):

Template:

```
<a
  [routerLink]="['1']"
  routerLinkActive="active"
  [ngClass]="{'link-disabled': isNotAllowed}">
  The Link
</a>
```

Component

```
get isNotAllowed(): boolean {
  return this.permissionService.isUserHasSomePermission(); // or canActivate method used in routes
}
```

Styles

```
.link-disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response :)

To clarify, I am aware that ngClass can be used with a standard boolean from the controller to apply a class to the DOM element.

I'm specifically wondering if there is something that works like routerLinkActive. The built in Angular directive routerLinkActive automatically checks the routerLink that is assigned to the DOM element against the current route you are on to apply a class to that DOM element.

I am looking for something like this but instead of checking the current route, it checks the state of the route's canActivate property.